# inserting data error code 23000 mysql pdo php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have a table in my databse

i am trying to insert some data inside it

but i keep getting pdo error code 23000

i tried the query manually and it worked so the proplem isn't with the query

my code :

```
<?
include ('config.php');
$text=$_POST['text'];
if (!isset ($text)) exit();
$query=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (post,userid,votes) VALUES (?,?,0)");
$query->bindValue(1,$text,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(2,$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$re=$query->execute();
if ($re)
echo 'Added';
else die($query->errorcode()." ".$query->errorinfo());
?>
```

and config look like

```
<?
session_start();
try{
$db=new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8','root','');
}
catch (PDOException $error) {
    echo $error->getmessage();
}
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$password=$_SESSION['password'];
?>
```

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string`?  Get rid of that!  It's useless here.

Comment: Mixing MySQL APIs. Just delete `$text=mysql_real_escape_string ($text);`

Comment: Do you see anything more than just the `23000` code?  An *actual* error message, by chance?

Comment: i deleted mysql_real_escape_string and the problem still

Comment: @RocketHazmat i get "23000 Array" the error code and error info

Comment: @user2973413: Try `var_dump($query->errorInfo());`.  You can't echo an array.

Comment: Add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Comment: @RocketHazmat array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "23000"
  [1]=>
  int(1048)
  [2]=>
  string(30) "Column 'userid' cannot be null"
}

Comment: @user2973413: Well, there ya go.  Your `$id` is null :-)

Comment: i added $id2=(int) $id; and it's working now @RocketHazmat Thanks A lot !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check MySQL docs?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_key

Looks like you have a duplicate key in DB. My guess userid.

If you have an auto-increment on userid no need to pass it on creation.

Looking at your code it:

1. Gets user from session
2. Adds this user to DB

So if you run script more than once it'll give 23000 error.

Yes and how did userid got in to session?

Comment: 23000 is the SQL state, not the error, the error is 1062.

Comment: In my case it was a foreign key violation that caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

1062 error code means "dublicate entry"

Comment: This seems to be more like comment but not an answer. Please see [How do i write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)